# Kotlin: I have a problem while switching from one Activity to another?

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I have a problem when I want to switch between two activities.

This is my code on the first activity. I want to switch to the CatDoorActivity.

```
modifier = Modifier.clickable {
            val intent = Intent(this, CatDoorActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("UUID", deviceUUID).putExtra("TITLE", deviceTitle)
            this.startActivity(intent)
        }
```

My Problem is this exception after running that code:

```
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.mycatbellproject/com.example.mycatbellproject.CatDoorActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2065)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1727)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5314)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:705)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5272)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:686)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5658)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5611)
        at com.example.mycatbellproject.MainActivity$CardItem$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:255)
        at com.example.mycatbellproject.MainActivity$CardItem$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:254)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$2.invoke-k-4lQ0M(Clickable.kt:153)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$2.invoke(Clickable.kt:142)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.TapGestureDetectorKt$detectTapAndPress$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(TapGestureDetector.kt:223)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:178)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:166)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:397)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:431)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:420)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeWith(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:328)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter$PointerEventHandlerCoroutine.offerPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:511)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter.dispatchPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:406)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter.onPointerEvent-H0pRuoY(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:419)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:310)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:297)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:297)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:297)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:297)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.NodeParent.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:179)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.HitPathTracker.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputEventProcessor.process-BIzXfog(PointerInputEventProcessor.kt:80)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.sendMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1205)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.handleMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1155)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchTouchEvent(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1095)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3118)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2799)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:488)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1871)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4125)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:446)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:14568)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6016)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5819)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5310)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5485)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5542)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5367)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5333)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5341)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5314)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8080)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8031)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7992)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8203)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:220)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.runtime.BroadcastFrameClock@f19bf6c, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@fd19935, AndroidUiDispatcher@cea91ca]
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7109 SIG: 9
```

I have added the activity to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
            android:name=".CatDoorActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCatbellProject"/>
```

The bottom of the exception says something about coroutines. I use them in for my room database. Do I get a problem intending a new activity and switching to it while using coroutines in my room database in the first activity? I use the room database viewmodel in my first activity but I dont use that on my second activity.

That is my second activity so far:

```
class CatDoorActivity : ComponentActivity(){

    private var uuid: String = ""
    private var title: String = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if(intent.extras != null) {
            uuid = intent.extras!!.get("UUID") as String
            title = intent.extras!!.get("TITLE") as String
        }


        setContent {
            MyCatbellProjectTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    MenuScreenUI()
                }
            }
        }
    }
...
```

The Repository of my room db uses the coroutines:

```
class DeviceRepository(application: Application) {
    val searchResults = MutableLiveData<List<Device>>()
    private var deviceDao: DeviceDao?
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
    val allDevices: LiveData<List<Device>>?

    fun insertDevice(newDevice: Device) {
        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            asyncInsert(newDevice)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun asyncInsert(device: Device) {
        deviceDao?.addDevice(device)
    }

    fun deleteDevice(id: Int) {
        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            asyncDelete(id)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun  asyncDelete(id: Int) {
        deviceDao?.deleteDevice(id)
    }

    fun findDevice(name: String) {
        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {

            searchResults.value = asyncFind(name).await()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun  asyncFind(name: String): Deferred<List<Device>?> =
        coroutineScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            return@async deviceDao?.findDevice(name)
        }


    init {
        val db: DeviceRoomDatabase? = DeviceRoomDatabase.getDatabse(application)
        deviceDao = db?.deviceDao()
        allDevices = deviceDao?.getAllDevices()
    }
}
```

Comment: In your manifest, using the `.` prefix shortcut for the activity name requires the Activity class to be in the same package as the `applicationId` in your build.gradle. If it doesn't match, the name in the manifest must be fully qualified.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both Activities are in the same scope as the applicationId in the build.grade. I double checked it now. Could there be any other reason? @Tenfour04

Comment: Edit your question and post your manifest. Also what the is the package name (usually the first line in the Kotlin file) in the file containing `CatDoorActivity`?